# Searching through Table connections in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, connection

Suppose I have two tables, one called zombies (id, name, graveyard), and one called weapons (id, name, strength, zombie_id).  Weapons :belongs_to Zombies What's the easiest way to find the weapon that has a zombie of name 'jack'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Weapon.includes(:zombie).where("zombies.name = ?", "jack")
```

This will return a collection, so if you want just the first, append `.first` to that query.

So in conclusion: includes will do a join, but also keep around the table included so you can reference it in the where clause.

Comment: if you append .first() at the end, wouldn't you get an exception if nothing will be found?

Comment: What does .includes() do?  Why is it necessary?  and why do you use `"zombies.name = ?", "jack"` instead of `:zombie => {:name => "jack"}`

Comment: @mkk No, because it will return an empty array (`[]`), and then when you call `.first` it will just return `nil`.

Comment: @joshim5 `.includes()` does a table join but keeps around the table so you can reference it. You can't do what you suggested because `:zombie` isn't the name of any column in your `Weapon` table.

Comment: But Weapon `belongs_to` Zombie

Comment: You should think about how it is under the hood. A little research in to how databases and relationships work would be helpful, too. But basically, you have a table for Weapon with database columns: id, name, strength, zombie_id. That's it. The zombie_id matches a row in the Zombie table. That is how you can interact between them, by that one unique ID.